# Return arrays that have a matching intersection

Tags: ruby

I have an array:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,4]
```

And more arrays:

```
b =[[1,2,3], [1,1,4], [7,3,4], [1,5,6,1]]
```

For each element in `b`, `b_i`, I want to know:

- is there some `b_i` such that `a  & b_i == b_i`, and
- what is that `b_i`

This is what I am thinking

```
def get_matching(a, b)
   b.each {|b_i|
      return b_i if (a & b_i) == b_i
   }
end
```

Where can I check whether the return value is nil or not to determine the answer to the first question? Though, maybe I can implement them as two separate functions so that checking whether such a matching exists doesn't need to actually return the matching.

Assume I only need the first matching if there are many.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not any more efficient but it *is* a little more ruby-esque using [Enumerable#detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect)

```
def get_matching(a, b)
  b.detect{ |b_i| (a & b_i) == b_i }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to do `return nil` at the end of your function.

A better way is:

```
def get_matching(a, b)
   b.find do |b_i|
      (a & b_i) == b_i
   end
end
```

Also keep in mind that array equality cares about the order of the elements.  It might be better to write:

```
(b_i - a).empty?
```

Comment: So it would be more like `((a & b_i) - b_i).empty?` to ignore order. Thanks I didn't consider order of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that there's a reason to use [Ruby Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)

```
require 'set'

def get_matching(a,b)
  a = a.to_set  
  b.detect { |b_i| b_i.to_set.subset?(a) }
end
```

Of course it's not the shortest answer but if you have a lot of similar tasks then using Set can be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

This should return all arrays where b_i is a subset or equal to a:

```
b.select { |b_i| (b_i - a).empty? }
```

Comment: Thanks, that will also be useful!